# Error: : is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++

My assignment is to create a program to manage a restaurant's activity, which includes a user reconizing feature and many other features.I am required to submit this assignment in only 1 .cpp file so i tried to compress the code into only 1 file :D. Here is what i have done so far in creating the user interface:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class UserInterface{
public:
    typedef UserInterface super;
    static int user_input;
    static void menu(){
        int input;
        print();
        setInput(input);
        execute();
    }
    static void print(){
        cout << "Welcome to the Restaurant Managing program!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your ID. The ID of chef is 0 and the ID of customers is a positive integer: ";
    };
    static bool setInput(int input){
        cin >> input;
        if (input >= 0){
            user_input = input;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    };
    static void execute(){
        switch (user_input){
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            Customer::menu();
            break;

        }

    };

};


class Customer :public UserInterface{
public:
    static void print(){
        cout << "1.Exit" << endl << "2.Make an order" << endl << "3.View orders" << endl << "4.Change order" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your ID: ";
    }
    static bool setInput(int input){
        cin >> input;
        if (input >= 1 && input <= 4){
            user_input = input;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    };
    static void exit(){
        super::menu();
    };
    static void makeOrder(){};
    static void viewOrder(){};
    static void changeOrder(){};
    static void execute(){
        switch (user_input){
        case 1:
            exit();
            break;
        }
    };
};

int UserInterface::user_input;
int main(){
    int input;

    UserInterface::menu();
    system("pause");
}
```

The problem is that when i compile this code i get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2653: 'Customer' : is not a class or namespace name
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong here and what else can i do to improve my code?

Comment: You cannot call a derived classes static function that way. The design is weird BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to call `Customer::menu();`, the compiler has not yet seen the `Customer` class. That's exactly what the error message is saying: *"Customer is not a class or namespace name."*

Even if it knew that `Customer` was the name of a class, it would not know whether it really had a `menu()` member function or not. It does not yet know that `Customer` is derived from `UserInterface` and inherits the `menu` function.

One solution is to split `UserInterface::execute` into a **declaration**, which can go *before* the definition of `Customer`, and a **definition**, which can go after *after* the definition of `Customer`:

```
class UserInterface { // start definition of UserInterface class
// ...
    static void execute(); // declaration of execute() function

}; // end definition of UserInterface class


class Customer : public UserInterface { // start definition of Customer class
// ...

}; // end definition of Customer class


void UserInterface::execute() { // start definition of execute() function
    switch (user_input){
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        Customer::menu();
        break;
    }
}; // end definition of execute() function
```

---

Another solution is to just call the function without the qualification:

```
static void execute(){
    switch (user_input){
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        menu();
        break;
    }
};
```

It depends on what you really want to achieve. Perhaps you later want to make `menu` a non-static function and override it in the derived class, then you can no longer use this easy solution.

Generally, I'd say you should reconsider your entire class design, because it seems needlessly complicated.

---

P.S.: Pay attention to compiler warnings:

```
warning C4101: 'input': unreferenced local variable
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'input' used
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this function

```
static void execute(){
    switch (user_input){
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        Customer::menu();
        break;

    }

};
```

after the definition the class `Customer`.

Take into account that declaration of the local variable `input` in the function below

```
static void menu(){
    int input;
    print();
    setInput(input);
    execute();
}
```

does not make sense because this variable is not used in the function.